# PowerShell Icacls permissions with domain group

Tags: powershell, icacls

I am trying to use icacls to set permissions for a domain group, but for some reason it is not working.

```
icacls "C:\Temp\ACL" /T /C /grant ("Everyone"+':F') ("System"+':F') ("Administrators"+':F') ("DOMAIN\groupname"+':C') >> C:\temp\c.log
```

I am trying to run it with Powershell, but I get the following error:

```
Invalid parameter "DOMAIN\groupname:C"
```

I have tried multiple solutions, and it works without `("DOMAIN\groupname"+':C')`.

Comment: Have you tried using the Set-ACL cmdlet instead?

Comment: Are `Domain` and `GroupName` variables that contain values? If so you need to use `$Domain` and `$GroupName`

Comment: @Clayton no, these are placeholder (redacted info)

Answer (score 2):

I had an old script that did this... your code looked correct, very similar to mine.
However I was granting Full control, and you were granting Change.
Other CLI tools like `SUBINACL`, `CALCS` have used "C" for Change, but it would seem `ICACLS` decided to use "M" for Modify.

If you change `("DOMAIN\groupname"+':C')` to `("DOMAIN\groupname"+':M')` you'll have better luck

From the ICACLS usage output:

```
perm is a permission mask and can be specified in one of two forms:
    a sequence of simple rights:
            N - no access
            F - full access
            M - modify access
            RX - read and execute access
            R - read-only access
            W - write-only access
            D - delete access
```

Answer (score 2):

As Clayton pointed out, the access control would be `M` rather than `C`. I would also note in addition that most of the extra characters you are inserting on the command line aren't necessary. PowerShell is pretty good at parsing the command line without so much "help." This should work as expected:

```
icacls C:\Temp\ACL /T /C /grant Everyone:F System:F Administrators:F DOMAIN\GroupName:M
```

You only need to include the quotes if something contains a space in it (this is the same as if you were typing the command at the `cmd.exe` prompt). Sometimes you have to change things a bit, but mostly it will "just work."

For additional information, see this article:

[IT Pro Today - Running Executables in PowerShell](http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/running-executables-powershell)

Comment: I'd add to this that even if you did need the quotes I'd probably pass it into invoke-cmd rather than stitch it together in the command

Comment: `Invoke-Command` is usually unnecessary.

Comment: For sure, it's for neatness /styling rather than functionality, and can occasionally even iron out these issues.